# Calling Lua function from C++ not working with 2 defined functions

Tags: c++, lua

I have a Lua script that I wrote and I have two functions inside it:

```
function CallbackServerStatus ()
    print("Status exec")
end

function CallbackServerInit ()
    print("Server initialized\n")
end
```

And this is how I am trying to call my Lua function in C++:

```
printf("LUA | Exec LUA: CallbackServerInit()\n");
luaL_dofile(LuaEngine::state, "loaders/test.lua");
lua_getglobal(LuaEngine::state, "CallbackServerInit");
lua_pcall(LuaEngine::state, 0, 0, 0);
```

But in the console `"Server initialized\n"` is no where to be seen. Am I doing something wrong here?? There isn't even an error, and I only see `"Server initialized\n"` when I remove the `CallbackServerStatus()` function.

Comment: What does `lua_pcall` return? If it is an error, what are the contents of the error message that was pushed on the stack?

Comment: What does `luaL_dofile` return? If there is an error, the functions are not defined.

Comment: I get an error when I call lua_pcall: `attempt to call a nil value`. It doesn't pop an error when I remove the first function in my LUA script though, I just don't understand.

Comment: @Zinglish well it means `CallbackServerStatus()` is not registered if you say so.

Comment: Can you load your Lua script into Lua running in a console without errors?

Comment: My LUA script runs fine with no errors.

Comment: If your Lua script loads and runs fine from the console, then you are either not loading the same script from your C++ code, or you are spelling the name of the function differently in the script and in the C++ call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found out that there was a non printing character in my script that was causing the script to fail.

Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to restructure your code too.

```
void execute(std::string szScript)
{
  int nStatus = 0;

  nStatus = luaL_loadfile(L, szScript.c_str());
  if(nStatus == 0){ nStatus = lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0); }

  error(nStatus);
}

void callFunction(std::string szName)
{
    int nStatus = 0;

    lua_getglobal(L, szName.c_str());
    nStatus = lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);

    error(nStatus);
}

void error(int nStatus)
{
    if(nStatus != 0)
    {
      std::string szError = lua_tostring(L, -1);
      szError = "LUA:\n" + szError;
      MessageBox(NULL, szError.c_str(), "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
      lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
}
```

I've wrote this for my application. You can use it too. This way you can observe any kind of error at compiling scripts or calling functions.

```
execute("C:\test.lua");
callFunction("MyFunc");
```

Comment: Thank you for this :) it's helpful. I am just trying to get this thing to run though, then structure the code how you have done it and I can't even seem to get this to run :/

Comment: @Zinglish That's the whole point. Restructure your code with mine and then when you want to execute your script, if there would be any error it'll be popped out.